# Problem with mail exchange in gmail

Tags: email, gmail, sendmail

I had setup an email server using which I can send instant email to any other email server also I can send mail to gmail but I cannot receive immediately. It takes almost 3hrs to receive email from gmail. How to fix this error.

My mail server domain is WWW.SOFTMAIL.ME

Answer (score 1):

Email is not instant messaging and there's nothing that guarantees instant delivery. It may be the case most of the time, but it is not guaranteed. Furthermore, you cannot do anything to speedup delivery from Gmail, since you are not in control of their servers.